# Dropdown list default value

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have populated my dropdown list using a table adapter object, it displays lists of cities. How do I make a default value? for example "Select your city"

This is the dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
          ID="list_city" runat="server" DataSourceID="CityObject"
          DataTextField="city" class="form-control" DataValueField="ID">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Please give us more information & the code that you are currently using.

Comment: @kyriacoss Their is no code. The dropdown list is populated from a database, its all interface and not backend

Comment: Show the code where you do what you explain. The `<asp:control source="something" /> <asp:something />` part maybe

Comment: Btw: You could probably in Page_Load set the selected value of the controller

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian Updated it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AppendDataBoundItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="list_city" runat="server" DataSourceID="CityObject"
      DataTextField="city" class="form-control" DataValueField="ID" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select Your City" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the default value after your databind.

```
list_city.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select your city", ""));
list_city.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the control after you have bound with the OnDataBound.
This is done pretty in the blind. so it might not work tight off the bat, but something along these lines should work.

Website.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList
            ID="list_city" runat="server" DataSourceID="CityObject" OnDataBound="list_city_DataBound"
            DataTextField="city" class="form-control" DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Website.aspx.cs

```
protected void list_city_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list_city.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select your city", "0"));
}
```